# Yii2: Passing $model to external function

Tags: gridview, model, yii2

I have several Gridviews, all of which have a few common columns containing algorithms for counting and summing numbers. In order to centrally maintain these columns, I have created an external class which I import. It is working well.

Here is an example:
Gridview:

```
        Column::percentPositive(),
        Column::countMinusOne(),
        Column::countZero(),
        Column::countPlusOne(),
```

Column Class:

```
    public static function countMinusOne()
{
    $x = [
        'attribute' => 'countMinusOne',
        'label' => '-1 ',
        'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'col-60 text-red'],
        'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'text-center text-red'],
    ];

    return $x;
}
```

My problem:
Each model is obviously slightly different and for some columns I need to pass a particular $model parameter to the static function. I was hoping that this would work:

```
Column::CountMinusOne($model->invalidated),
```

which I could then use like this:

```
public static function countMinusOne($invalidated)
{
    $x = [
        'attribute' => 'countMinusOne',
        'label' => function() use($invalidated){
             // do my stuff here
         },
        'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'col-60 text-red'],
        'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'text-center text-red'],
    ];

    return $x;
}
```

However, even though I am in GridView, $model is not recognised and I get an error: "Undefined variable: model". I can confirm that $model is available in the conventional GridView column elements but is not available to pass to static function.

How can I pass $model->invalidated to my function??

Many thanks

**Update based on Bizley response:**

Here is where I can get to:

Class:

```
namespace app\models\columns;    
class Column extends \yii\grid\DataColumn
    {

        public $type;
        public $name;

        public function init()
        {
            parent::init();

            // here you can set all attributes based on 'type'
            switch ($this->type) {
                case 'test':
                    $this->value = function(){ return "hello ".$this->name;};
                    break;
```

GridView:

```
    [
        'class' => 'app\models\columns\Column',
        'type' => 'test',
        'name' => function($model){ return $model->name;}
    ],
```

I get an error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string.

What I find odd is that within GridView, $model->name will return "world" but when I pass $model->name to the class it is an enormous object and I cannot access the name. I was expecting "world" to be passed as a string to the class but, instead, there is an object.

All I want to do is pass the name to the class but don't seem to be able to.

If I dump the object that exists in the class, I can see the name deep within the object:

```
   ...
   [1] => app\models\Sponsor Object
     (
      ...
     [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
         (
            [id] => 120
            [name] => World
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to extend `yii\grid\DataColumn` class with your own and use it inside the GridView.

Now you can set this widget like:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        // ...
        [
            'class' => \namespace\to\YourColumn::className(),
            // configuration for YourColumn
        ]
    ],
]) ?>
```

With this you can do whatever you want with the data by setting YourColumn properties and adding / overriding its methods.

For dynamic value you use `value` property that can be a closure with signature:

```
function ($model, $key, $index, $column)
```

so there is your missing `$model` here.

**Edit**: (more details)

Example:

Column class:

```
namespace app\models\columns

class Column extends \yii\grid\DataColumn
{
    public $type;

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        // here you can set all attributes based on 'type'
        switch ($this->type) {
            case 'percentPositive':
                // ...
                break;
            case 'countMinusOne':
                // parameters taken from question
                $this->attribute = 'countMinusOne';
                $this->label = '-1 ';
                $this->contentOptions = ['class' => 'col-60 text-red'];
                $this->headerOptions = ['class' => 'text-center text-red'];
                break;
            case 'countZero':
                // ...
                break;
            case 'countPlusOne':
                // ...
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now GridView:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        // ...
        [
            'class' => 'app\models\columns\Column',
            'type' => 'countMinusOne',
            'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                // use the proper attribute you need
                // in Column class it's $this->value
                return $model->name;
            }
        ]
    ],
]) ?>
```

Comment: Many thanks Bizley. I have managed to partly implement your solution but I don't fully understand your advice. I have amended my question and include an update based on what I have managed to implement from your guidance. Please advise. Many thanks

Comment: I've added simplified example in my answer.

Comment: ok... I am making some progress but still cannot create a working solution. One last piece of guidance would be most appreciated. Many thanks. Question updated.

Comment: Don't pass the `name` as a closure without having method in column class that will properly utilize it. It's better to stick with `value` and if you want to add something to it automatically you can override `getDataCellValue()` method from the parent class.

Comment: Ok... but... in my final working version I need to pass through two parameters: a value and a status. If the status is "invalid" colour is overrriden and cell is grey. If "valid" then the colour is based on the value. You description seems to only accommodate one value. Am I missing something? Thanks for all your help and I am sorry that I am not fully grasping the solution.

Comment: You can use `'contentOptions'` for that with a closure as well, see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-column.html#$contentOptions-detail This whole "your own extended column class" thing seems like an overkill now if you want only to set value and cell color based on $model attributes but general idea of changing the configuration with 'type' only stays.

Comment: I am comfortable with 'contentOptions' etc - but what I need (and all I need) is to be able to pass $model->status (or $model->value->status etc) to the static function. Everything else works.  Each view has 'status' at a slightly different layer of the $model. Hence my desire to have a solution like: Column::CountMinusOne($model->status). If I could somehow convert $model->status to a string, all would be solved but it passes the whole function (or whole model) into my static function. If I write Column::CountMinusOne('invalid') it works great. Sorry this is such a pain

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not really sure what to tell you more. If you want to modify cell's value according to $model - use `value` with closure; if you want to modify cell's HTML options according to $model - use `contentOptions` with closure.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will go through your examples again and spend a bit of time on this. Thanks for your help - apologies I didn't follow.